Error: "Can't evaluate field Release in type string" in Helm helper template
I have the following template in _helpers.tpl:
{{/* Get the system admin username from secret
*/}}
{{- define "get-system-admin-username-value" -}}
  {{- $secretObj := (lookup "v1" "Secret" .Release.Namespace "my-secret") }}
  {{- if and $secretObj (index $secretObj.data "username") }}
    {{- $secretValue := (index $secretObj.data "username") | b64dec }}
    {{- $secretValue }}
  {{- else }}
    {{- "undefined" }}
  {{- end }}
{{- end }}

I call this function the following way:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod

metadata:
  name: "{{ .Chart.Name }}"
  labels:
    {{- include "labels" . | nindent 4 }}
  namespace: {{ default "undefined" $.Values.env.NAMESPACE }}
spec:
  containers:
   - name: "{{ $.Chart.Name }}--xxx"
     env:
        - name: SYSTEM_ADMIN_USERNAME
          value: {{ include "get-system-admin-username-value" . | default "undefined" }}
        - name: SYSTEM_ADMIN_PASSWORD
          value: {{ include "get-system-admin-password-value" . | default "undefined" }}

When running, I get the following error:
error calling include: template: _helpers.tpl: executing "get-system-admin-username-value" at <.Release.Namespace>: can't evaluate field Release in type string

What seems to be the issue here?
I've already tried passing the namespace from the helm chart as a string, I get the same error, also excluding the if statement, and every possible combination of root context '$'.

In your actual YAML file, do you have a range loop or with block that's not included in the question?

Yes I do. there are multiple conditional containers in this Pod, and some of them are created via a range loop like so:
{{- range .Values.env.CONFIG_FILES }}
- name: "{{ $Chart.Name }}
env:
- name: SYSTEM_ADMIN_USERNAME

Within the range loop, . will have the current value from the loop; that's the source of the error.  I'd generally recommend that you only run one container per pod, though, and it's almost always better to create higher-level objects like Deployments than to directly create Pod objects.  Will an administrator ever need to change the set of containers at deploy time; does this actually make sense as a configuration parameter?

There are three containers in total, one main, and two auxilliary helper ones. Yes, as the containers form depending on multiple factors that get clear during pre-build checks.
I’ll take a look into how to pass Release.Namespace outside the range.

I've managed to resolve the issue by saving the value of . to the top of the helm chart via {{ $top := . }}. Thank you for your help!
